# Trying to define an object with two inputted variables, why doesn't class update my object?

Tags: python, class, object

Just trying to understand classes and objects. Why can't i get the object ID to update with my new values? It returns "MatrixSquare instance has no attribute 'ID'" Didn't I define that in the class?

```
#tomb of Bibi - initial code of classes and objects - started 1/30/19
#last revision:  1/31/2019
#---------------------------------------------------------------------
class MatrixSquare:
   def __init__(self):
    'Contains primary shapes and partial or full constructed shapes'
    # initialize row, col
    row=""
    col=""
    ID=[row,col]


# first object in class: MatrixSquare1        
MatrixSquare1=MatrixSquare()

#debug only- print variable ID from object
MatrixSquare1=MatrixSquare()
MatrixSquare1.row=input("row:")
MatrixSquare1.col=input("col:")
print("1st object row ",MatrixSquare1.row)
print("1st object col ",MatrixSquare1.col)
print("ist object ID ",MatrixSquare1.ID)

#debug only -create another object with new var id
MatrixSquare2=MatrixSquare()
MatrixSquare2.row=raw_input("row:")
MatrixSquare2.col=raw_input("col:")
print("2nd object row: ",MatrixSquare2.row)
print("2nd object col: ",MatrixSquare2.col)
print("2nd object ID",MatrixSquare2.ID)
```

I expect the matrixsquare.id to be updated with the new values inputted. But it returns instance has no attribute 'ID'"

Comment: Those are merely local variables in your constructor.

Answer (score 0):

For `ID` to be an attribute of the instance, you need to use `self` (this is how Python knows that is your intention)

so change your code to:

```
class MatrixSquare:
   def __init__(self):
    'Contains primary shapes and partial or full constructed shapes'
    # initialize row, col
    self.row=""
    self.col=""
    self.ID=[self.row,self.col]
```

The same principle would apply for any updates or uses from within any instance method

However, from your code by updating `col` and `row` `ID` will not automatically update (you'll have to write something that tells Python to update it every-time you update `col` or `row`; for example by using a setter)

This could work:

```
class MatrixSquare:
    def __init__(self):
        'Contains primary shapes and partial or full constructed shapes'
        # initialize row, col
        self._row=""
        self._col=""
        self.ID=[self._row,self._col]

    @property
    def col(self):
        return self._col

    @property
    def row(self):
        return self._row

    @col.setter
    def col(self,col):
        self._col = col
        self.ID = [self._row,self._col]

    @row.setter
    def row(self,row):
        self._row = row
        self.ID = [self._row,self._col]
```

Comment: An even simpler solution would be not to use `_col` and `_row` at all, and directly read and write into `self.ID[0]` and `self.ID[1]`.

Comment: Also, this might be a good place to consider using the property annotation manually, rather than with @. That way, you can assign the same actual function as the setter to all the different properties, and then delete the method itself.

Comment: I'll be happy to simplify if you can shown an example - the above way is how I currently use it. Thanks